# Interrupt Service Routine in C - function at specific address

Tags: microcontroller, pic, c, interrupts, mplab

I need to add an Interrupt Service Routine (ISR) to existing code in C for a [PIC18F4620](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/39626b.pdf) and a [PIC18F46K22](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41412F.pdf). As you can see in section 9 (of both datasheets), these devices have multiple interrupt vectors: `0x0008` for high priority interrupts, `0x0018` for low priority interrupts.

I'd like to have an answer which is useful in many cases, so the question would be: *how can I make a function on a specific program memory address?* For the ISR, this address would be `0x0008` or `0x0018`.

If it's of any use, I'm using the MPLAB C18 compiler, v3.44.

Related: [C coding design - function pointers?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/56058/17592)

Comment: For the record, there is no generic way in standard C to allocate code at a specific address. You have to use compiler/linker-specific ways, such as #pragmas.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll find the information you need in the compiler's manual: [MPLAB C18 C COMPILER USER'S GUIDE](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/51288f.pdf).

From page 37 of the user's guide:

> MPLAB C18 does not automatically place an ISR at the interrupt vector. Commonly, a `GOTO` instruction is placed at the interrupt vector for transferring control to the ISR proper. For example:

```
void lowPriorityISR(void);

#pragma code low_vector=0x18
void interrupt_at_low_vector(void) { 
    _asm GOTO lowPriorityISR _endasm 
}
#pragma code

#pragma interruptlow lowPriorityISR
void lowPriorityISR() {
}
```

When implementing a *high* priority ISR, you *cannot* use the `interrupthigh` pragma as you would expect. You'll have to use the `interrupt` pragma instead, as is described [here](http://www.microchip.com/forums/m97595-print.aspx).

If you can change the compiler: using interrupts is easier in the Microchip XC8 or HI-TECH PICC compilers.

Comment: Had to copy the code to my project anyway :-)